# Explain oracle Vector.add()

Tags: java, vector, collections

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add(E)

This page for Vector.add() states this method returns 'true' then proceeds to  link to the Collections.add().

Does the Vector.add() return false as well, like Collections.add()?

Also on the oracle page it states "Specified by:", does that mean Vector.add has the same description as Collections.add and List.add? And what does it mean by "Overrides:"?

Does Vector.add throw all the same exceptions as Collection / List / AbstractList .add()?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, the Javadoc of the subclass takes precedence over the Javadoc of the superclass.  So if the `Vector` Javadoc does not say these exceptions can be thrown or these values can be returned, then assume that it cannot.  (The Javadoc for the `Collection` interface is simply provided for reference to tell you why `true` is always returned.)